# Dynamic collection design of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am designing notification center for a social network, and I am just thinking about to store one user's notifications in one collection named notification_$userid ($userid is dynamic).

And for such design, I think that can be read and writed faster than putting all users' notifications in only one collection. But is there any disadvantage for it? or is there any limitation for collection amount of one db?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to rethink this.
The reason is that no matter how flexible is a noSQL database, it can be still huge. And the sharding, and if you grow later you might want to consider migrating to a cluster, etc.
I would recommend you that you solve this task on the application layer.

Here's how I would do:

1) user comes, makes something that notifies the other users
2) this "gesture" is not stored in your database as notifications, but in the related user "notifiocations" cell.
3) the user's "noticifcations" cell is similar to an array - in MongoDB it is an array and you just store objects there

This way you "personalize" your notifications in your DB also and you have avoided using a "notifications" collection. The only thing you need to do is to push that notification into the related users "notifications" array.

Comment: The current version of the notification center is just likes what you mentioned. But I just worried about the padding factor that mongo would copy the doc and make the write action very slow.

Comment: No, actually, you don't have to worry about that. I guess you have an authentication before users can do anything and you can get all the info about the logged in user right after it has been validated. =)
I have written a chatter based on MongoDB this way. I get the user's infos while authenticating, and I use 2 collections for the actual messaging. One temporarily, until both of the users have read that message (doc) and one for "archives". When a user sends a message it is recorded to both tables, and when both of them have read it, it is deleted from the temporary collection. =)

Comment: @benqus what if this archive array will grow extremely fast? How long you will be able to keep it readable? Or all archives stored in huge collection? Sorry, but this moment is unclear for me.